# Is it possible to include multiple file types when using the `FileType` event?

Tags: vim, latex

For example, I'd like to map a key when in a `tex`-like file, which includes many different flavor of `tex` files. Do I have to use multiple commands like this?

```
au FileType tex nm <C-H> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
au FileType latex nm <C-H> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
au FileType context nm <C-H> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
au FileType plaintex nm <C-H> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
...
```

Answer (score 52):

Absolutely:

```
au FileType tex,latex,context,plaintex nm <C-H> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```

Some thoughts:

- Should be using a buffer local mapping instead of a global mapping
- Using short names has *only* cons and *zero* pros. Don't.
- This autocmd should be in a group
- Autocmd's should be cleared (inside a group) so that re-sourcing is not a problem
- Maybe use a after ftplugin script. e.g. `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/tex.vim` instead of an `:autocmd` as they are easier to manage
- look into romainl's [idiomatic vimrc](https://gist.github.com/romainl/9ecd7b09a693816997ba) for more vimrc do's/don't's

Cleaned up version:

```
augroup tex_mappings
    autocmd!
    autocmd FileType tex,latex,context,plaintex nmap <buffer> <c-h> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
augroup END
```

Alternatively add the following to `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/txt.vim`:

```
nmap <buffer> <c-h> <Plug>IMAP_JumpForward
```

Note: with the ftplugin approach you will need to add this line for each `FileType` (or use `:source`)

For more help see:

```
:h :au
:h :aug
:h :map-local
:h after-directory
```

Comment: Catchy punchlines for the win!